# Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle #1

Tags: rebus, movies

**Background:**

Your love for Hollywood movies and remarkable ability to remember movie titles is finally going to serve a purpose. There was indeed a time when you almost believed your mother's words, as she scorned you: "Lazing in front of the television is not going to pay for the rent!" You knew better all along. As you and the rest of your family listen to the directions of your late, and wealthy, Uncle Rob's will, you cannot help but smile as the executor reads "... and thus half of my fortune will indeed go toward a sole beneficiary. Namely he who solves the puzzles as depicted below".

As you are each given a paper with four Hollywood movie rebus puzzles, you begin to smile. You know the answer to each.

How will you answer?

**Puzzle #1**
[image]

> [Next puzzle - #2 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-2)

Comment: Reason for down vote??

Comment: Partly inspired by the riddle in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> Spiderman

This is because

> The periscope represents the word **spy**.
> The middle picture is a perm, but with the p crossed out to become a d, so it's **derm**.
> The ant has its t crossed out so it's **an**.
> Putting this all together we get the answer, **spiderman**.

Comment: Well done Tryth