# Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle #2

Tags: rebus, movies

**Background:**

Your love for Hollywood movies and remarkable ability to remember movie titles is finally going to serve a purpose. There was indeed a time when you almost believed your mother's words, as she scorned you: "Lazing in front of the television is not going to pay for the rent!" You knew better all along. As you and the rest of your family listen to the directions of your late, and wealthy, Uncle Rob's will, you cannot help but smile as the executor reads "... and thus half of my fortune will indeed go toward a sole beneficiary. Namely he who solves the puzzles as depicted below".

As you are each given a paper with four Hollywood movie rebus puzzles, you begin to smile. You know the answer to each.

How will you answer?

**Can you guess the movie for the 2nd puzzle?**
[image]

> Next puzzle: [#3 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15465/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-3)
>
> Fee first puzzle: [#1 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-1)

Comment: Also think about adding a little bit of flavor text with these. I've upvoted both but someone clearly thinks they are deserving of downvotes. It might be due to the sort of bland background to solving the puzzle. Maybe a connecting story between the puzzles? (John is traveling through Hollywood finding clues to the location of a secret Age of Ultron deleted scene... or something like that)

Comment: That's helpful mistereman22.

Comment: The downvotes may be just because they're too easy. There's been no real challenge in any of the three so far (IMO): the pictures are easy to interpret and even if one or two aren't, it's easy to fill in the gaps when you know the answer is a film title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This one looks like it's

> **Catch Me If You Can**

Explanation:

> - The first picture is pretty clearly a **cat**
>  - The second picture is China minus ina, which becomes **ch**
>  - This is a user icon, which represents **me**
>  - This icon represents the .gif file format, with the first letter crossed out so that it becomes **if** (thanks, pacoverflow!)
>  - The finger is almost certainly pointing at **you**
>  - This is most definitely a tin **can**!

Comment: For the 4th clue, it crossed out the 1 to remove the first letter.

Comment: @pacoverflow, you're right, that's it! Thank you :)

Comment: Weird. For some reason, all I see on the third clue is a Pokémon ball.

Comment: Clearly the answer. I couldnt figure out the 4th clue but found the title without it. Thanks also - pacoverflow (and Bailey M)

Comment: Oh come on, how is the last one not a [database](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=database+icon&tbm=isch)?

Comment: @ace because it has an inside?