# Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle #3

Tags: rebus, movies

This is the third puzzle in the Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle series. See the others here.

> [Puzzle #1 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-1)
>
> [Puzzle #2 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-2)

.
**Background**

Your love for Hollywood movies and remarkable ability to remember movie titles is finally going to serve a purpose. There was indeed a time when you almost believed your mother’s words, as she scorned you: “Lazing in front of the television is not going to pay for the rent!” You knew better all along. As you and the rest of your family listen to the directions of your late, and wealthy, Uncle Rob’s will, you cannot help but smile as the executor reads “… and thus half of my fortune will indeed go toward a sole beneficiary. Namely he who solves the puzzles as depicted below”.
As you are each given a paper with four Hollywood movie rebus puzzles, you begin to smile. You know the answer to each.

**How will you answer the third puzzle?**
[image]

> [Once solved, see the next puzzle - Puzzle #4 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15742/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-4)

Comment: I think it's slightly stretching the definition to call these puzzles "rebus". There are no positional clues where something is in/above/under something else. The symbols are immediately recognizable - the only challenge here is whether the last one is child or kid, and after pronouncing the first three, that gets settled quickly. While movie titles are somewhat constrained grammatically, making your job harder, I would like to see these be more rebus-y.

Comment: @KateGregory - appreciate the comment, however, I do think this is still a rebus. From wikipedia: "A rebus is an allusional device that uses pictures to represent words or parts of words."

Comment: Examples of rebus'. (1) Three rebus-style "escort cards" from the 1860s or 1870s - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#/media/File:RebusEscortCardsCirca1865.jpg or (2) a German rebus from ca. 1620 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#/media/File:Arolsen_Klebeband_18_041_3.JPG

Comment: No doubt this is a rebus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> **Karate Kid**

Explanation:

> The first item is a **car**.
>  The second is the symbol "**at**".
>  The third is a cup of **tea**.
>  The fourth is a **kid**.
>  If you spell it out, it sounds like "Karate Kid".