# Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle #4

Tags: rebus, movies

This is the fourth puzzle in the Hollywood Movie Rebus Puzzle series. See the others here.

> [Puzzle #1 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-1)
>
> [Puzzle #2 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-2)
>
> [Puzzle #3 Hollywood Rebus Movie Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15465/hollywood-movie-rebus-puzzle-3)

.
**Background**

Your love for Hollywood movies and remarkable ability to remember movie titles is finally going to serve a purpose. There was indeed a time when you almost believed your mother’s words, as she scorned you: “Lazing in front of the television is not going to pay for the rent!” You knew better all along. As you and the rest of your family listen to the directions of your late, and wealthy, Uncle Rob’s will, you cannot help but smile as the executor reads “… and thus half of my fortune will indeed go toward a sole beneficiary. Namely he who solves the puzzles as depicted below”.
As you are each given a paper with four Hollywood movie rebus puzzles, you begin to smile. You know the answer to each.

**How will you answer the fourth puzzle?**
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> FORREST GUMP

Reason:

> FOR (four [o'clock]) + REST (person lying in bed) + GUMP ([bubble] gum + p)